# Can we use contradiction to prove the "only if" part of this problem?

Tags: analysis

Consider the following problem.

Let ($a_{kl}) \in \Bbb R^ {\infty \times\infty}$  be a double real sequence such that $sup\{{\sum_{j=1}^\infty|a_{ij}|:i \in \Bbb N }\}<1$. Show that a bounded real sequence $(x_m)$ satisfies $$x_i=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j ,  i=1,2,... $$iff $(x_m)=(0,0,...)$

I am able to show the "if" part, but when it comes to the "only if" part, I want to assume that there exists a non-zero term in the sequence ($x_m$) to get a contradiction to the condition that $(x_m)$ is bounded, but I failed. Does any one have idea how to show the "only if" part? Thanks.

Comment: Let $b$ be the least upper bound of $(x_m)$ and $s<1$ be the supremum in the expression. Every $x_i < sb$. You can find a contradiction from this because $b$ is the *least* upper bound.

Comment: Wow, it works, this is amazing, thank you